# Netsuite saved search for all contacts (Prospects, Customers) and leads

Tags: netsuite

I have customers and prospects as companies and a lead can be individual or company. I need to create a saved search that returns all of the contacts of prospects, contacts of customers and all of the leads in one list. I can do a contact search where status = all available statuses and I get the primary contact of customers, primary contact of prospects and all leads (individual or company) If I add contact.name to the results tab, I get all contacts of prospects and customers but I lose all of the individual leads. I'm attaching image of the criteria and results field. This setup returns the primary contacts and all leads but I need all contacts. My goal is to get a list of every contact or lead in NetSuite to send to external system.
[image]
[image]

Comment: The join your asking about is in beta right now.

Answer (score 1):

Do a Customer search with the following criteria:

USE EXPRESSIONS = YES

**Contact : Internal ID**   is not none         **Or**

**Is Individual**   is true

In your results you can use a Formula(Text) to get the proper name and/or email:
decode({isperson},'Yes',{altname},{contact.entityid})

Answer (score 1):

Finally heard back from support. It turns out you can tell NetSuite to treat individuals like contacts:

When you navigate to Setup > Company > General Preferences, you have there an option to SHOW INDIVIDUALS AS CONTACTS. When this feature is enabled, individual type customer records will now show in list of Contacts

Answer (score 0):

You will need two separate searches to accomplish this. One for the Leads and one for the Contacts as these are two separate Tables in NetSuite.

Comment: This is not possible in NetSuite, at least not the type of UNION you're asking for. You will need two separate searches.